# How do I prevent the div.tooltip-inner from disappearing when the mouse is over it in a tooltip created using Bootstrap v5.3.2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

**HTML**

```
<aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
<ul class="sidebar_content">
<li data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" aria-label="Item-1" data-bs-html="true"                                                                    data-bs-original-title="<a href='#'>Item-1</a>">
</ul>
</aside>
```

**JS**

```
hamBurger.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar");
    sidebar.classList.toggle("minimize");
    const isMinimized = sidebar.classList.contains("minimize");
    if (isMinimized) {
        enableTooltips(); 
    } else {
        disableTooltips();
    }
});

function enableTooltips() {
    const tooltipTriggerListInSidebar = document.querySelectorAll('#sidebar.minimize li[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]');
    tooltipTriggerListInSidebar.forEach(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
        new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
            delay: {
                "show": 0,
                "hide": 250
            }
        });
    });
}

function disableTooltips() {
    const tooltipTriggerListInSidebar = document.querySelectorAll('#sidebar li[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]');
    tooltipTriggerListInSidebar.forEach(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
        const tooltipInstance = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance(tooltipTriggerEl);
        if (tooltipInstance) {
            tooltipInstance.disable();
        }
    });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVvLd.png)

I want to prevent the div.tooltip-inner from closing 250ms after the mouse is over it. Additionally, the div should disappear when the mouse leaves the tooltip-inner.

It seems like you're having trouble preventing the closure of the div.tooltip-inner when the mouse is over it. Even with the specified delay of 250ms for the hide action, the tooltip still disappears.